# Click doesnt work on iOS 8 simulator [Xcode 6.0.1]

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6.0.1 on a Yosemite DP. When I target my app to run on an iPhone 5S/6/6 Plus simulator (iOS 8), the app launches just fine. But, I am unable to perform any click events. It looks as if the screen is frozen. I am able to rotate the screen, use the Home and Lock commands from the menu. But, other than that nothing happens within the app. I tried to Reset the Contents and Settings. It works at times. But, it has stopped working now. I have even tried restarting my iMac; but no luck. Someone please let me know if you are facing this issue and if so, how you have resolved the same.

Spindump log:

```
Architecture:    i386
Parent:          launchd_sim [33451]
Responsible:     launchd_sim [33451]
UID:             501
Task size:       17543 pages (+2)
CPU Time:        0.005s
Importance:      Adaptive, Boosted

Thread 0x185129   priority 47         cpu time   0.005s
1001 start + 1 (libdyld.dylib) [0x7ba8ac9]
1001 main + 76 (main.m:36 in Norton Online Family) [0x100e9c]
  1001 UIApplicationMain + 1526 (UIKit) [0x19f6e16]
    1001 GSEventRun + 104 (GraphicsServices) [0x418c08c]
      1001 GSEventRunModal + 192 (GraphicsServices) [0x418c24f]
        1001 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 (CoreFoundation) [0x3cfcfdb]
          1001 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443 (CoreFoundation) [0x3cfd1ab]
            1000 __CFRunLoopRun + 1400 (CoreFoundation) [0x3cfd9e8]
              1000 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214 (CoreFoundation) [0x3cfe606]
                1000 mach_msg_trap + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7ea3f7a]
                 *1000 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002167d0]
            1    __CFRunLoopRun + 2451 (CoreFoundation) [0x3cfde03]
              1    __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 510 (CoreFoundation) [0x3d089ce]
                1    __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53 (CoreFoundation) [0x3d08a65]
                  1    migHelperRecievePortCallout + 209 (AppSupport) [0x69b2ac7]
                    1    _XReceivedStatusBarDataAndActions + 101 (UIKit) [0x1f359f0]
                      1    _UIStatusBarReceivedStatusBarDataAndActions + 62 (UIKit) [0x1f32085]
                        1    -[UIStatusBarServer _receivedStatusBarData:actions:] + 62 (UIKit) [0x1f31f37]
                          1    -[UIStatusBar statusBarServer:didReceiveStatusBarData:withActions:] + 156 (UIKit) [0x1f40979]
                            1    -[UIStatusBarForegroundView setStatusBarData:actions:animated:] + 893 (UIKit) [0x1f267e6]
                              1    -[UIStatusBarForegroundView _setStatusBarData:actions:animated:] + 493 (UIKit) [0x1f263f4]
                                1    -[UIStatusBarLayoutManager updateItemsWithData:actions:animated:] + 236 (UIKit) [0x1f2b595]
                                  1    -[UIStatusBarLayoutManager _updateItemView:withData:actions:animated:] + 136 (UIKit) [0x1f2bbb5]
                                    1    -[UIStatusBarItemView setStatusBarData:actions:] + 93 (UIKit) [0x1f2a288]
                                      1    -[UIStatusBarItemView updateContentsAndWidth] + 36 (UIKit) [0x1f2a769]
                                        1    -[UIStatusBarTimeItemView contentsImage] + 46 (UIKit) [0x1f485bb]
                                          1    -[UIStatusBarItemView imageWithText:] + 268 (UIKit) [0x1f2ae12]
                                            1    -[UIStatusBarForegroundStyleAttributes imageWithText:ofItemType:forWidth:lineBreakMode:letterSpacing:textAlignment:style:withLegibilityStyle:legibilityStrength:] + 304 (UIKit) [0x22a99be]
                                              1    +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 89 (Foundation) [0x159dc22]
                                                1    -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 159 (Foundation) [0x159a377]
                                                  1    _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 270 (CoreFoundation) [0x3dc1abe]
                                                    1    CFRelease + 652 (CoreFoundation) [0x3ca51bc]
                                                      1    __CFStringDeallocate + 150 (CoreFoundation) [0x3ca7c76]
                                                        1    CFAllocatorDeallocate + 100 (CoreFoundation) [0x3c922d4]
                                                          1    __CFAllocatorSystemDeallocate + 24 (CoreFoundation) [0x3ca7cb8]
                                                            1    szone_free + 2001 (libsystem_malloc.dylib) [0x7d77b75]
                                                              1    <executing in user space>

Thread 0x18512b   priority 31        
1001 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 60 (libdispatch.dylib) [0x7b71114]
1001 kevent64 + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7ea9992]
 *1001 ??? (mach_kernel + 3960080) [0xffffff80005c6d10]

Thread 0x185134   priority 33        
1001 thread_start + 34 (libsystem_pthread.dylib) [0x7eebcf2]
1001 _pthread_start + 130 (libsystem_pthread.dylib) [0x7ee6485]
  1001 _pthread_body + 144 (libsystem_pthread.dylib) [0x7ee65fb]
    1001 __NSThread__main__ + 1326 (Foundation) [0x15e9ab0]
      1001 -[NSThread main] + 76 (Foundation) [0x15e9b57]
        1001 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 469 (CFNetwork) [0x1080bb6]
          1001 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123 (CoreFoundation) [0x3cfcfdb]
            1001 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443 (CoreFoundation) [0x3cfd1ab]
              1001 __CFRunLoopRun + 1400 (CoreFoundation) [0x3cfd9e8]
                1001 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214 (CoreFoundation) [0x3cfe606]
                  1001 mach_msg_trap + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7ea3f7a]
                   *1001 ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002167d0]

Thread 0x185136   priority 31        
1001 thread_start + 34 (libsystem_pthread.dylib) [0x7eebcf2]
1001 _pthread_start + 130 (libsystem_pthread.dylib) [0x7ee6485]
  1001 _pthread_body + 144 (libsystem_pthread.dylib) [0x7ee65fb]
    1001 __select + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7ea8ace]
     *1001 ??? (mach_kernel + 4080224) [0xffffff80005e4260]

Thread 0x185625   priority 31        
274 start_wqthread + 30 (libsystem_pthread.dylib) [0x7eebcce]
274 __workq_kernreturn + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7ea9046]
 *274 wq_unpark_continue + 0 (pthread) [0xffffff7f80c166ae]



*0xffffff7f80c13000 - 0xffffff7f80c1afff  com.apple.kec.pthread 1.0 (1) <882075E6-12C4-3225-8750-928715183739> /System/Library/Extensions/pthread.kext/Contents/MacOS/pthread
*0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff80007a823a  mach_kernel (2422.115.4) <9477416E-7BCA-3679-AF97-E1EAAD3DD5A0> /mach_kernel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a spindump focused on your app to see if you're main thread is blocked.

`sudo spindump [name of your process]`

Comment: Doesnt seems to be of much help. I happened to install Xcode in a different machine and faced the same issue. I ran the app on the simulator and it worked fine. Without stopping the app, I tried to run the app again. That is when it stops working for me. Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Is the app actually running or not?  If it is, take a spindump.  If it isn't, it was likely SIGKILLed by SpringBoard due to a timing bug (try again or finger launch it)

Comment: The app is running. But, I get the following error "assertion failed: 13F34 12A365: libxpc.dylib + 69090 [A6323EFF-4EA3-3D2B-957D-C71CF8CE4C38]: 0x7d" when it hangs.

Comment: That error indicates that something was using a bad domain when communicating with launchd.  That seems possibly consistent with the race condition/timing bug I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I also get the following message on the console.com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.DC0E4B2D-A38B-48D0-9CA9-DE9E43813642.launchd_sim[26312] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.

Comment: Yeah, you can just ignore that message.

Comment: I have attached my spindump log along with my question. Can you please let me know if you find any issues with this log?

Comment: The entire spindump is too large to attach here.  launchd_sim is all that I can see in your question, and it certainly looks fine.  You'd need to look at your process and see what it is doing.  Also look at SpringBoard and backboardd.

Comment: I am not able to find any deadlocks or recursive loops in those processes as well.

Comment: It happens in only one of the projects that I had recently updated to Xcode 6. Maybe there is something I am missing w.r.t. that.